# Do you have any idea how to design this link for email?

Tags: email, html-email, email-attachments

thanks for helping me first of all.

I'm trying to format this email, but the link can not be put inside the container.

I do not know what properties I can use.

In html it works very well but when I see it in a mail client it does not work

```html
<table width="650" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolr="#005daa" width="650px" bgcolor="#ffffff">
               [imagen_1]
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="650" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px">

                <p style="margin: 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #5c6670; text-align: left;">
                    [texto_1]
                </p><br>

                <p style="margin: 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #ed1b24; text-align: left; font-weight: bold">
                    <a style="text-decoration:none; margin: 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #ed1b24; text-align: left; font-weight: bold"
                        href="https://{{ $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] }}/validating-email/{{$data->token}}">
                        
CLICK HERE IN THE FOLLOWING LINK <br>TO CONFIRM YOUR MAIL


                    </a>
                </p>
                <p style="margin: 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #ed1b24; text-align: left; font-weight: bold">
                   and start enjoying great benefits.
                </p>
            </td>
            
           
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
             <table width="550" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                 <tr>
                    <td bgcolr="#005daa" width="650px" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    
                      <a rel="nofollow" style="widh: 500px;     word-break: break-all;">
                       

https://dominio.com/confirm-email/eyJpdiI6IkhkWlp6NlVQSXcrd0R6WnVWXC9za1wvUT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJ3WUwycEt5UFwvbU9IVnBnWDJYejNlem1MYytHcFhMSk56OFwvOGZUdmVhYzdRbUgyNEM5b0VkMlhkdlBFNGxrcGQiLCJtYWMiOiI4MmZkNjllZjI3MTNhMDhiNTU1NmRmZjhmNmFiNzljYWM3ZGY0N2UzZTFlZjA5MjlkNmY4MDc5NWY1OGYwMWRjIn0= 
 

                      </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
</table>
```

So it looks in the emails

I already try a thousand things and not one works.

you have some idea of ​​how I can do so that the link is set and does not remain in a single line

```html
    <table width="650" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolr="#005daa" width="650px" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                   [imagen_1]
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="650" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 30px">

                    <p style="margin: 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #5c6670; text-align: left;">
                        [texto_1]
                    </p><br>

                    <p style="margin: 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #ed1b24; text-align: left; font-weight: bold">
                        <a style="text-decoration:none; margin: 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #ed1b24; text-align: left; font-weight: bold"
                            href="https://{{ $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] }}/validating-email/{{$data->token}}">
                            
    CLICK HERE IN THE FOLLOWING LINK <br>TO CONFIRM YOUR MAIL


                        </a>
                    </p>
                    <p style="margin: 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #ed1b24; text-align: left; font-weight: bold">
                       and start enjoying great benefits.
                    </p>
                </td>
                
               
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>
                 <table width="550" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                     <tr>
                        <td bgcolr="#005daa" width="650px" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                        
                          <a rel="nofollow" style="widh: 500px;">
                           

    https://dominio.com/confirm-email/eyJpdiI6IkhkWlp6NlVQSXcrd0R6WnVWXC9za1wvUT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJ3WUwycEt5UFwvbU9IVnBnWDJYejNlem1MYytHcFhMSk56OFwvOGZUdmVhYzdRbUgyNEM5b0VkMlhkdlBFNGxrcGQiLCJtYWMiOiI4MmZkNjllZjI3MTNhMDhiNTU1NmRmZjhmNmFiNzljYWM3ZGY0N2UzZTFlZjA5MjlkNmY4MDc5NWY1OGYwMWRjIn0= 
     

                          </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>
                </td>
             </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to make an href work?

This is how a basic href works:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">stackoverflow.com</a>
```

In your case it should look like this:

```
<a href="https://dominio.com/confirm-email/eyJpdiI6IkhkWlp6NlVQSXcrd0R6WnVWXC9za1wvUT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJ3WUwycEt5UFwvbU9IVnBnWDJYejNlem1MYytHcFhMSk56OFwvOGZUdmVhYzdRbUgyNEM5b0VkMlhkdlBFNGxrcGQiLCJtYWMiOiI4MmZkNjllZjI3MTNhMDhiNTU1NmRmZjhmNmFiNzljYWM3ZGY0N2UzZTFlZjA5MjlkNmY4MDc5NWY1OGYwMWRjIn0="
target="_blank" rel="nofollow" style="widh: 500px; word-break: break-all;">CLICK HERE IN THE FOLLOWING LINK<br />
TO CONFIRM YOUR MAIL<br />
and start enjoying great benefits.</a>
```

Or do this if you only want the url to link to the website:

```
<a href="https://dominio.com/confirm-email/eyJpdiI6IkhkWlp6NlVQSXcrd0R6WnVWXC9za1wvUT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJ3WUwycEt5UFwvbU9IVnBnWDJYejNlem1MYytHcFhMSk56OFwvOGZUdmVhYzdRbUgyNEM5b0VkMlhkdlBFNGxrcGQiLCJtYWMiOiI4MmZkNjllZjI3MTNhMDhiNTU1NmRmZjhmNmFiNzljYWM3ZGY0N2UzZTFlZjA5MjlkNmY4MDc5NWY1OGYwMWRjIn0="
target="_blank">https://dominio.com/confirm-email/eyJpdiI6IkhkWlp6NlVQSXcrd0R6WnVWXC9za1wvUT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJ3WUwycEt5UFwvbU9IVnBnWDJYejNlem1MYytHcFhMSk56OFwvOGZUdmVhYzdRbUgyNEM5b0VkMlhkdlBFNGxrcGQiLCJtYWMiOiI4MmZkNjllZjI3MTNhMDhiNTU1NmRmZjhmNmFiNzljYWM3ZGY0N2UzZTFlZjA5MjlkNmY4MDc5NWY1OGYwMWRjIn0=</a>
```

All of this can be on one line. I added the breaks to make it easier to see the code.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm not doing href, but a text that contains the address, his intention is that the user can copy and paste the link when it does not work in a mail client